# Django override save method with changing field value

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I need some help with overriding save method with changing field value.

I have such structure:

**models.py**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, validators=[MinLengthValidator(3)])
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True,
                               related_name='children',
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE
                               )
```

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, validators=[MinLengthValidator(3)])
    to_category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                                    blank=True, null=True,
                                    )
    to_categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, blank=True,
                                           related_name='categories',
                                           )

    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

So I can't find a correct sollution for save method. I can select category on the "to_category" and categories on "to_categories" field, but I need if I selected one of the categories on the "to_category" field then save the Product, this selected field must be automatically selected on the "to_categories" field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a sollution.

admin.py:

```
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   ...

   def save_related(self, request, form, formsets, change):
        super(ProductAdmin, self).save_related(request, form, formsets, change)
        category = Category.objects.get(id=form.instance.to_category.id)
        form.instance.to_categories.add(category)
```